# MTurk: Posting experimental conditions simultaneously, but only allow each worker to see one of the conditions

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I have an experiment with multiple conditions. In each experiment, I am asking Turkers to rate a piece of news article, but I am changing the presentation across experimental conditions. I need to post all conditions to Turk simultaneously, but allow each worker to see only one of the many conditions. The first time a worker attempts a hit, he is randomly assigned to one of the experimental condition (say A) and then if he attempts any subsequent hits he should be shown tasks related to the same experimental condition (A) and not to others (B, C, etc.).

I know that one can use Qualification requirements to prevent workers to repeat surveys, but this is not possible in the case I described above, because I need to post different experimental conditions simultaneously, unlike surveys where you do phase1, retrieve worker IDs who did the task and then block (or assign qualification) so that they cannot attempt the survey in phase 2.

Anyways, short version of the question is: How do I assign a worker randomly to an experimental condition and then ensure he is assigned to the same one in any subsequent hits, provided I post all conditions simultaneously. Is there a way to retrieve worker IDs while they see the HIT and then assign them the corresponding experimental condition task. The closest I can find is this [paper](http://dub.washington.edu/djangosite/media/papers/toomim-utility.pdf) (page 5), where they use IFrame to find the worker ID.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend here is not using true randomization. Instead, use javascript to retrieve the worker's `workerId` parameter, which will be passed as a URL query argument to the HIT. Then, in the HIT itself, use javascript to nonrandomly show workers an article based upon some portion of their workerId (e.g., the last two characters).

As a fuller example, create an array of all two-element alphanumeric combinations. Randomly assign each of those combinations to a condition. Then, when the worker accepts the HIT, extract their workerId, match the last two characters thereof to the condition based on the array, and then display the appropriate content to the worker. So, in essence, you're nonrandomly assigning people based on their workerId, but that identifier is basically assigned randomly.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how is this better than simple randomization. Also, how will you ensure that you get all the required assignments for all the conditions? Wouldn't a round robin assignment make more sense?

Comment: @tan You can't ensure balance across conditions in this way (unless you know the distribution of workerIds, that's true, but it solves your basic issue about how to achieve this natively in MTurk (without relying on another server to handle it for you) and do it with just one HIT. The issues you raise in your comment are not part of your question; if they're vital, you should edit your question to include them.